# Rotating user stats

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Supposing I have a table with the following schema:

```
int pitchId, int pitcherId, int pitchType, timestamp pitchTimeStamp
```

where we keep track of every pitch a pitcher has pitched.  Now let's say, I want to only include the last 100 pitches and purge anything other than the last 100 pitches for each `pitcherId`.  I know one possible solution is to cycle through each pitcherId in PHP and find the 100th pitchId in the past for that `pitcherId` and delete anything older than that.

However, I assume there must be a more efficient way of doing this, either through stored procedures or in my mind, preferably triggers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an SQL statement like this.

```
DELETE FROM pitch p 
WHERE NOT (p.pitchid IN 
          (SELECT p2.pitchid FROM pitchid p2 ORDER BY p2.pitchid DESC LIMIT 100))
```

Comment: looks good! Can't even believe I didn't think of a subselect, but will keep this question unanswered to see if other people have other suggestions.

Comment: Won't this delete ALL pitches but 100 for _all pitchers_, rather than all but 100 for _each_ pitcher?

Comment: actually yes, but I assume I could join p and p2 on p.pitcherId = p2.pitcherId.